# Why doesn't it display the names?

Tags: php

This website is supposed to display people's names in the boxes, but they're not there.

Link to the website: http://dorkhub.tdoyle.tk/

This is the code:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($aVar, "SELECT name FROM users
    ORDER BY RAND()");
$aName1 = mysqli_fetch_row($query1);
$name1 = $aName1['name'];

$query2 = mysqli_query($aVar, "SELECT name FROM users
    ORDER BY RAND()");
$aName2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
$name2 = $aName2['name'];

?>

<title>DorkHub. The online name-rating website.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body bgcolor='EAEAEA'>
<center>
<div id='TITLE'>
    <h2>DorkHub. The online name-rating website.</h2>
</div>
    <p>
    <br>
    <h3><?php echo $name1; ?></h3><h4> against </h4><h3><?php echo $name2; ?></h3>
    <br><br>
    <h2 style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>Who's sounds the dorkiest?</h2>
    <br><br>
    <div id='vote'>
    <h3 id='done' style='margin-right: 10px'>VOTE FOR FIRST</h3><h3 id='done'>VOTE FOR LAST</h3>
```

Comment: can you show us the table structure......

Comment: You should do some basic debugging yourself. Are all your fields named correctly (hint: no), print for yourself what is in that array (hint: use `var_dump`, `print_r` or a debugger), check that even if you do the assignment `$name1 = $aName1['name'];` correct, it won't help you, as in your html-code you are not using this variable but still the array. So fix that as well. Etc. Please put some effort in it yourself first.

Comment: @Nanne - If I could up-vote a comment more then I would. Sound advice.

Comment: Your column is called `name` but you are using `name1` and `name2`.

Comment: I've changed that, still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have taken incorrect field names

Change:

```
$name1 = $aName1['name1'];
```

to

```
$name1 = $aName1['name'];
```

For the second,

Change

```
$name1 = $aName2['name2'];
```

to

```
$name2 = $aName2['name'];
```

Also, Change

```
 <h3><?php echo $aName2['name2'];; ?></h3><h4> against </h4><h3><?php echo $aName1['name1'];; ?></h3>
```

To

```
<h3><?php echo $aName2['name']; ?></h3><h4> against </h4><h3><?php echo $aName1['name']; ?></h3>
```

Again,

Change

```
$aName2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
```

To

```
$aName2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: No. It only displays one name.

Comment: Now, it must work. Please refer the updated answer. Please let me know.

Comment: No, it still only displays one name.

Comment: Which one $name1 or $name2?

Comment: $name1 isn't appearing.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you have name, replace it with name1 or vice versa as it is in your database :

And

```
$aName2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
```

to

```
$aName3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
```

you should also change the `$aName2` to $`aName3`, other wise you have to make `$aName2` an array and for accessing value use `foreach loop`